# how to implement Radio Button with ng-switch in angular5?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular5, frontend, ng-switch

Working with angular5 , i found this code in internet , i tried to run it  as i want the same thing in my application , it doesn't work as expected  ,the problem is that  i can check all the radio Button , also i can see the first message  even  before chooosing any of the radio button elements.

```
<form>
      Pick a topic:
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="dogs">Dogs
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="tuts">Tutorials
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="cars">Cars
    </form>

    <div ng-switch="myVar">
      <div ng-switch-when="dogs">
         <h1>Dogs</h1>
         <p>Welcome to a world of dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="tuts">
         <h1>Tutorials</h1>
         <p>Learn from examples.</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="cars">
         <h1>Cars</h1>
         <p>Read about cars.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea why this doesnt work for me ? i have not imported any library to work with this exemple .

This is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form_radio) im using for this exemple , but it doesnt work for me as in this link .

Comment: this is not angular5 its angularjs and what is the issue?

Comment: Ah okey , i was wondering why its not working ,how can i do the same in angular v5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following with angular

```
<input type="radio" value="dogs" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> A
<input type="radio" value="tuts" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> B
<input type="radio" value="cars" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> C
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9k7ju?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Ah oky , but i want to display only simple messages , there is no need for my case to create component , can we do that ?

Comment: what do you mean by messages? you need component wiht angular

Comment: Yes thank you for your help , this works now for my case :) , i appreciate your help